# Execution order against authorization filter

Tags: fluent-security

Using Fluent Security, I have configured website access using DenyAnonymousAccess, DenyAuthenticationAccess and RequireRole. However, since `HandleSecurityAttribute` is not an authorization filter, all logic to handle `DenyAnonymousAccessPolicyViolation` only get executed after authorization filter, such as `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`.

This means that if current user's authentication ticket is timeout, any action decorated with `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` will throw exception since the token is not created for anonymous user.

So is there a way to work around this? I am currently looking at two solutions:

1. reate my own authorization filter to perform exact what `HandleSecurityAttribute` security does.
2. Use the global `Authorize` filer to handle authentication and leave role / other access policy to FluentSecurity.

**Update:**

I checked in a demo at github, the username and password for this is dev1 and devdev. I set the timeout forms authentication to 1 minute. So if you login, and wait for one minute, then click on logoff, you will get the token is not created for anonymous user. In normal MVC, this won't happen since [Authorize] runs before [ValidateAntiForgeryToken], which redirect user back to login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had any problems with this. Make sure that you put the **HandleSecurityAttribute** first in the filters list!

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleSecurityAttribute(), 0);
```

Comment: Hi Kristoffer, the problem is `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is authorize action filter, which always runs before the normal `ActionFilter`. The order of 0 only guarantees `HnadleSecurityAttribute` to be executed before any other `ActionFilter` not authorize action filter.

Comment: Hi Kristoffer, I checked in a demo at [github](https://github.com/melcloud/demo_issue_with_fluent_security), the username and password for this is `dev1` and `devdev`. I set the timeout forms authentication to 1 minute. So if you login, and wait for one minute, then click on logoff, you will get the token is not created for anonymous user. In normal MVC, this won't happen since `[Authorize]` runs before `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, which redirect user back to login screen.

Comment: Thanks for posting the demo on github. I'll have a look at this issue next and will get back to you once I have any news on this issue.

Comment: I tried inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute as well as simply implementing IAuthorizationFilter. In both cases, it did not make any difference. Did you ever try this yourself and if so, did you get it working?

Comment: Had another look at it and it seems you need to specify an order even if we implement the IAuthorizationFilter. And you must set it to -1 in order for it to run before ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute. So this is what works:

filters.Add(new HandleSecurityAttribute(), -1);

I will make this change in FluentSecurity and make sure it is part of the upcoming beta release. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!